# make a List from class elements

Tags: list, flutter, dart, categories, getter-setter

I have a simple question, I have dummy data about some products and I need to take all categories into the new list. How can I do it?

```
class Products with ChangeNotifier {
List<Product> _productItems = [
Product(
  id: 'p1',
  title: 'Red Shirt',
  price: 29.99,
  category: 'shirts',
),
Product(
  id: 'p2',
  title: 'Trousers',
  description: 'A nice pair of trousers.',
  price: 59.99,
  category: 'Trousers',
),
Product(
  id: 'p3',
  title: 'Yellow Scarf',
  price: 19.99,
  category: 'Scarfs',
),
Product(
  id: 'p4',
  title: 'A Pan',
  price: 49.99,
  category: 'Pans',),];

   List<Product> get items {
    return [...items];
   }

   List<Product> get fovoriteItems {
   return _productItems.where((prodItem) => prodItem.isFavorite!).toList();
  }

   List<Product> get stockItems {
  return _productItems.where((prodItems) => prodItems.isStock!).toList();
  }

   List<Product> get categoriesList {}
    }
```

I need to take a `List` like `categories = [Shirts,Trousers,Scarfs,Pans];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem isn't clear but there are notable issues in your code. You firstly need to update your `items` method to return all the products. So update it to something like this:

```
List<Product> get items {
    return _productItems;
}
```

Then in the `get favoriteItems` method, you have not defined the `isFavorite` property in any of the dummy classes. So update them to include it. This also goes for your `get stockItems` method. Here's an example:

```
Product(
  id: 'p9',
  title: 'Apples',
  description: 'A delicious red treat',
  price: 1.99,
  category: 'Food',
  isFavorite: false,
  isStock: true, 
),
```

Also make sure to remove the `!` from prodItem.isFavorite! and prodItems.isStock! because this will give the opposite result.

The `categoriesList` method should be of type `String` because a category isn't necessarily product. Here's the implementation:

```
List<String> get categories {
    List<String> ctgrs = [];

    for (item in _productItems) {
        ctgrs.add(item.category);
    }

    return ctgrs;
}
```

I would also highly recommend using `UniqueKey()` or using the [UUID](https://pub.dev/packages/uuid) package for every product's `id` so you don't have to make a custom one for every product. Using UUID is very secure as well.

Comment: its work , thank you

Comment: @MuhammadTawil You are very welcome. Also since this helps, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<String> categories = [];
_productItems.forEach((element) {
  if (categories.indexOf(element.category) < 0) {//avoid duplicates
    categories.add(element.category);
  }
});
```

Comment: its work also , its better to be in function but its good thank you so much

Comment: Please remember to include an explanation, and not simply a block of code. We're not here to encourage copying-and-pasting, but rather to help future readers better understand the concepts.